# How to prevent this code duplication? - Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I use this piece of code in a big part of my templates:

```
{% if app.session.hasFlash('error') %}
        <div class="error">
            {{ app.session.flash('error') }}
        </div>
{% endif %}
```

but the word **error** is changing. Could you give me idea how to avoid code duplication?

With include or macro I can change only the div class, but what about the word error in app.session.flash? And is there sense in doing this, or it's better to leave it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include this with the "with" option. For example:

```
{% include 'AcmeDemoBundle:Tools:flash.html.twig' with {'flash':'error'} %}
```

And then in flash.html.twig do:

```
{% if app.session.hasFlash(flash) %}
        <div class="{{flash}}">
            {{ app.session.flash(flash) }}
        </div>
{% endif %}
```